# Activity Problem while home key pressed

Tags: android

I have @ activities... MasterGameActivity and GameActivity ... when i pressed the home key while i ma in Gameactivity, and while come back on game then it goes on MasterGameactivity ... i want that it should be on GameActivity...
Can aynone tell that which could be problem...

Comment: Which one does the launcher point to?

Answer (score 0):

Every time home is pressed the application goes to the background. and when u re launches the app it will show the launcher activity cause it is the new instance of your App.

Comment: if the activity has not been finished there is no reason the launcher activity will be called. It will call the same activity from where it left.

Comment: @user643144: can you please post your code snippet. Ideally that should not have happened.